# 'this' keyword refers to what object within an a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, scope

Basically I am trying to understand and learn the 'this' keyword's working principle in JavaScript.

As far as I understand 'this' refers to the object (function) that it is inside at that moment.

So, by believing this, I wanted to test the output of the simple code below:

```
<body>

<input type="button" value="Add Age" onclick="Outer()" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function Outer(){

if(typeof this.Father == 'undefined')
    {
        this.Father = 0; 
    }

this.Father+=2;
alert(this.Father);

inner();

        function inner(){
            if(typeof this.Son== 'undefined')
            {
                this.Son = 0;
            };

            this.Son++;
            alert(this.Son);
            alert(this.Father);
        };
};
</script>
</body>
```

And its output confuses me. Because in the inner() function, this.Son outputs the incremented integer value of the Son. But I expect this.Father to fail because inner() does not have a .Father attribute. But instead of throwing an exception it alerts the value of this.Father -Which seems

- a line above 'this' refers inner()
- and following line 'this' refers Outer()

At this point i have 2 questions in my mind actualy:

1. Does 'this' keyword refers always to
   the outer scope's housing even inside the inner functions?
2. And without having any instances declared 'this' keyword references what in the method? ( I mean without having something lik `var myFamily = new Outer()` )

Thanks,

burak ozdogan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is determined by the invocation pattern, that is, how a function object is being called.

There are 4 different kinds of invocation patterns:

1. method invocation: function are defined as a property of some object, and is called via the object using refinement, that is, `.`.

   a.func(); // `this` refers to the object, i.e., `a`.
2. function invocation: plain function call.

   func(); // `this` is bond to the global object.
3. constuctor invocation: well, it is a little complicated. Since constructors are used as, well, the consturctor method for the new function objects being `new`, `this` refers to the new function object being created.

   var func = new Func(); // `this` refers to `func` while in `Func` constructor)
4. apply invocation:

   func.apply(thisArg, argArray); // `this` is bond to the first argument

In another words, the `this` in your example all refers to the global object (your `onClick` call `Other()`). You should try using `new Other()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it is really useful information.
you can finds some more about invocation patterns in this article:

http://mcarthurgfx.com/blog/article/4-ways-functions-mess-with-this

Comment: And this one is also quite explanatory: Function invocation in JavaScript - contexts revisited - http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/08/24/function-invocation-in-javascript-contexts-revisited.aspx